# Too many regions in hbase because of small tables

Tags: hbase

We have multiple applications sharing a HBase cluster. Multiple apps process  timeseries data and load large number of lookup tables [few Kbs/Mbs] along with larger tables [GBs/TBs] for processing. These lookup tables are unique and cannot be shared between the apps.

Question: because of these small tables, the number of regions on an average in the region servers is 300+ and is increasing. Based on [this](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/important_configurations.html#bigger.regions) link and [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/49612/what-is-the-recommended-number-of-regions-per-regi.html) one, recommendation is to keep the number of regions between 100 to 200.

What are the recommendations to reduce the number of regions? What are the strategies to deal with such small tables/lookup tables in Hbase?

Comment: how many small tables do you have?

Comment: 200 out of the 500+ tables are small tables

Comment: Are region sizes same for large and small tables? As I understand just half of all tables are small. So why they impact the number of regions per servers differently than large tables?

Comment: I don't understand how much you gonna win from small tables rework. You say you have 300+ regions per node  and only 200 small tables. How many machines in cluster do you have? if 10, you win only 20 regions per node, if 20 machines you win 10regions per node, etc. Is it worth?